# Condition for row equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

> In $M_{m\times n}(F),$ all the matrices of rank $k$ are row-equivalent iff $n\le m$ and $k = n.$

Is it true? How to show the result? If we take $n >m$ then also we can have row equivalence in same rank matrices(not in all). Am I missing something? Any help.

I have come up with an counter example. Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then both $A$ and $B$ have same rank and they are row equivalent. But here $n = 3 > m = 2.$
So the result does not hold.
Am I right in this?

Comment: Just an FYI: Two matrices can have the same rank but not be row equivalent. For example, if you interchange the second and third column of your $B$ matrix, the rank of $B$ is unaffected but its row space changes. This change would mean $A$ and $B$ aren't row equivalent.

Comment: You quote a result for $n\le m$, and claim a counterexample with $n>m$. The stated result (the one with $n\le m$) is correct.

Comment: But how to prove the stated result then? @GerryMyerson

Comment: But the space spanned by the rows of B is equal to the space spanned by the rows of A ? @MatthewPilling

Comment: Yes, the matrices you wrote are row equivalent. But, if you interchange the last two columns of $B$, $A$ and $B$ will still have rank $2$ but they would no longer be row equivalent. In other words, matrices that have the same rank don't necessarily have to be row equivlent.

Comment: Okay I got it. So is my counterexample correct ? I mean I have shown there exist  2 row equivalent matrices with rank equal but the number of columns are greater than the number of rows. Also the rank is equal to the number of rows. Hence the sufficient part is not true I guess. @MatthewPilling

Comment: I think I see your problem @hiren_garai. Let's assume for the moment that $k=2$. If *all* rank $2$ matrices of a given size are row$-$equivalent, then we must have exactly $2$ columns and at least $2$ rows. Note that not all rank $2$ matrices of size $2\times 3$ are row$-$equivalent.

Comment: If $k=n\le m$ then after reduction to reduced row echelon form you know exactly what the matrix looks like, don't you, hiren?

Comment: Yes, it will have $k$ non zero linearly independent rows along with same columns ! Okay I got it. Then the two matrices will be similar. But what about the sufficient part ? If they are row equivalent, number of rows will be atleast equal to the number of columns ? I am unable to understand that part.

Comment: I got your point @MatthewPilling

Comment: If $n>m$, or if $n\le m$ but $k<n$, then it's easy to construct inequivalent matrices in reduced row-echelon form. E.g., $\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&1&0\cr0&0&0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&0&1\cr0&0&0\cr}$ for $m=n=3$, $k=2$.